# Whats the mistake in this my bubble sort program?

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort

I have checked again and again for any problems in the code but can't figure out why my bubble sorting program is not giving correct output. Can you please help me identify?

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

 using namespace std;

 main()

{
  int number[10];
  int temp=0;
  int i=0;

  cout<<"Please enter any ten numbers to sort one by one: "<<"\n";

  for (i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
      cin>>number[i];
      }
  i=0;

  for (i=0;i<10;i++)
  {

      if(number[i]>number[i+1])

      {
      temp=number[i+1];
      number[i+1]=number[i];
      number[i]=temp;
                          }

      }
      i=0;
      cout<<"The sorted numbers are given below:"<<"\n";

      for (i=0;i<10;i++)
      {
        cout<<number[i]<<"\n";  
          }

          getch();
  }
```

Edit:
I have accepted what you all said that there must be an outer loop. But again I'm thinking on what I have written. I think the ONLY loop with the bubble condition should do the sorting. Here is what I'm thinking:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    if(number[i]>number[i+1])
    {
        temp=number[i+1];
        number[i+1]=number[i];
        number[i]=temp;

    }
}
```

Now I explain what I am thinking what this loop "should" do. It will first compare number[0] with number[1]. If the condition is satisfied it will do what is in IF statement's body. Then i will be incremented by 1(i++). Then on next iteration the values compared will be number[1] with number[2]. Then why it does not happen and the loop exits after only pass? In other words may be I'm trying to ask IF statement does not repeat itself in for loop? In my opinion it does. I'm very thankful for help and views, my question might be of small level but that is how I will progress. Thanks.

Comment: first mistake is using bubblesort!  :)

Comment: it sorts just few numbers. Sometimes it does not sort any number at all. And sometimes correct output. I think its depending upon what and in what order I am giving the input. It should not be so.

Comment: I know Mitch bubble sort is slow algorithm but I need to learn to code all of them. Hope you understand.

Comment: it is not because its slow. It is pathelogically slow on more than a few hundred items. It has no place in production code.

Comment: Yes my instructor told me there are faster algorithms to come in our next chapters like quick sort. But as a student we need to know all of them and then analyze which is the best.

Comment: You could found out what was the problem on your own, if you just debug you're code.

Comment: +1 for remembering good-ol-dayys. But i think shell-sort is better :)

Comment: @MitchWheat: Does it matter ? You learn thousands of things that have no place in production code (what's the 4th of July signification ? who was Lafayette ?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You run the bubble loop only once - you should run it until everything is sorted
- Your bubble loop goes to ten, accessing `number[i+1]`, which is an undefined behavior

Here is how you can fix your main loop:

```
bool again;
do {
    again = false;
    for (i=0;i<9;i++)
    { //       ^-- Nine, not ten
        if(number[i]>number[i+1])
        {
            temp=number[i+1];
            number[i+1]=number[i];
            number[i]=temp;
            again = true;
        }
    }
} while (again);
```

Comment: typo. Changed before posting the question.

Comment: @user1643568 Edited. Once you fix the remaining two issues, your code works (here is a [link](http://ideone.com/AgZW4) to ideone with your running program).

Comment: Thank you very much dasblinkenlight!

Answer (score 3):

This is only the first pass of a Bubble Sort. You need to repeat your sort part until no sorting is performed during a pass.

Comment: Thank you very much. Clarified.

Answer (score 1):

Bubble sort is O(n*n)(worst case)---->need an inner-loop beginning from iteration to the end. Then you should put a checking if finished in the half-way to get better situations such as O(nlogn) or O(n).

```
for (i=0;i<9;i++)     //from 0 up to N-1
{ 
  failed=false;      //for the checking if finished
  for(int j=i+1;j<10) //from next element up to N
   {
     if(number[i]>number[j])
     {
         temp=number[j];
         number[j]=number[i];
         number[i]=temp;
         failed=true;
      }


   }
  if(!failed)break;         //if failed=false then it is done.
}
```

Your error was iterating only once from 0--->N

- Outer loop should go from 0--->N-1 since next element will be N at last.
- Inner loop should go from i+1 to N.  i+1 denotes `next` element.

If you need to break when it is completed before n*n iteratitons, you need to inform with a boolean

Example:

`Initial : 4 9 3 6 2 5 7`

```
1st pass: 4 3 6 2 5 7 9  ---> failed at many i(you see "9" bubbled )

2nd pass: 3 4 2 5 6 7 9 ---> failed at several i's(you see "6" bubbled)

3rd pass: 3 2 4 5 6 7 9 ---> failed(once) at 4 and 2(you see "4" bubbled)

4th pass: 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 ---> failed once at 2 and 3(3 bubbles)

5th pass: 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 --->same! did not fail. Finished without looping 2  more
```

Comment: no ! this is a strict o(n^2) version ! simply replace the for by a while(!sorted) { sorted = true; if (...) { sorted = false; ...}} and you get something that usually exits much earlier

Comment: yes, but the point of using bubble sort is being faster than slow sort.

Comment: -1: The code does not actually compile (there are several mistakes). Your description is not a description of the algorithm you implement (this moves the smallest value to the bottom each iteration. it is bubble sort like but not the classical one you see in books (as I don't see a value bubbling).

Answer (score 1):

its quite dangerous to have

```
int number[5];
```

and ask the user to enter 10 values ;-)

Comment: Lol. Initially I had 100 numbers then reduced to 5. And to show you people changed to ten. Just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You are going out of bounds of the array. Make the loop run 5 times, not 10.

Secondly you are trying to sort the array in just one pass.
Make nested loops. for complete sort.
For Example if you have this array.

```
3  4  1  2  6
```

After one pass, as you are doing, it would look like this.

```
3  1  2  4  6
```

So this array is not completely sorted. Make two loops for complete sorting.

And make sure to run the loops till `size - 1`

Answer (score 0):

It may be happening because you are declaring an array of size 5 `number[5]` but trying to enter and access 10 elements.

If you want to have 10 elements in the array declare it as `int number[10];`

And use the for loop as:

```
for (i=0;i<9;i++)     //from 0 up to N-1
{
  for(int j=i+1;j<10) //from next element up to N
   {
  if(number[i]>number[i+1])

     {
  temp=number[i+1];
  number[i+1]=number[i];
  number[i]=temp;
      }

   }
}
```